# Question regarding Limits and the use of L'hopital

Tags: limits

I am having trouble with this limit, and wondered if this step on line $5$ was allowed, where I used L'Hopital agian but in the numerator of the limit. Thanks in advance.

[image: ![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IONgu.png]

I have attatched a picture of my calculations.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. It's unclear exactly which line you are referring to. If you typeset the equation in [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site), then people will be more willing to help you. In addition, please provide more information about what part of the calculation is troubling you.

Comment: I'm sure that you have not done any calculations. It is important the sincerity. The font is very closer to Cambria Math.

Comment: It is a screenshot from my Microsoft word document. I'm terribly sorry for the format, however, I am not very experienced with Latex and other text editors.

Comment: @BreeZeriNoo: If you read the tutorial, including the section on calculus notation, then I think you will know enough to be able to typeset it. I'm only recommending this because some people object to people using pictures quite strongly, and you might receive downvotes otherwise.

Comment: Which one is line 5? Do you count lines of text? Even if you don't use Mathjax/Latex, please mark it somehow: red line, or star, or put a rectangle around the step which is unclear

Comment: @Andrei Yes I am terribly sorry. I have tried to mark it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a single application of L'Hospital,

$$\frac{\sqrt x\sin\sqrt x}{1-e^{-x}}\to\frac{\dfrac{\sin\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}+\dfrac{\cos\sqrt x}2}{e^{-x}}\to\frac{\dfrac12+\dfrac12}1.$$

Note that a second application of L'Hospital is not allowed (nor necessary), as the conditions for application are not fulfilled.

---

**Without l'Hospital:**

Let $x=t^2$ and $u=t^2$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sqrt x\sin\sqrt x}{1-e^{-x}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t\sin t}{1-e^{-t^2}}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^2}{1-e^{-t^2}}\frac{\sin t}t=\frac{\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\sin t}t}{\lim_{u\to 0}\dfrac{1-e^{-u}}u}=1$$

using well-known limits.